# How to prevent a selected option and a textbox from being cleared after pressing F5 In AngularJS, until a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a select option and a textbox,when a user select an option and enters text in a textbox that data gets saved in sql database.I need to know how to prevent the selected option and
text from textbox from being cleared when a user presses F5,until a button is clicked in AngularJS, than the select option and textbox can be cleared.Here is what I tried but it doesn't work.

JS

```
function Model($http) {
    var self = this;
    self.$http = $http;

    var CurrentDowntimeEvent = {};

  self.StartDowntimeEvent = function () {      
        var params= {
              DepartmentId:self.LineId
            , EventId: self.CurrentDowntimeEvent.EventId
            , CategoryId: self.CurrentDowntimeEvent.CategoryId
            , StartTime: self.CurrentDowntimeEvent.startTime
            , Comment: self.CurrentDowntimeEvent.Comment
        };

        Hesto.Ajax.ngget(self.$http, ADD_DOWNTIME_START, params, function (data) {
            self.CurrentDowntimeEvent = data.data[0];
            console.log(self.CurrentDowntimeEvent);
        });
    }

angular.module('myApp', [])

 .controller('DowntimeController', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.Model = new Model($http);
});

The CategoryId is the select option and the  Comment is the textbox.
```

HTML

```
 <select class="categories" ng-disabled="selectlistdisabled" ng-model="Model.CurrentDowntimeEvent.CategoryId" ng-click="display()">
        <option value= {{downtimeCategory.CategoryId}} ng-repeat="downtimeCategory in Model.DowntimeCategories">{{downtimeCategory.CategoryName}}</option>
        </select> 
 <button ng-click="Model.StartDowntimeEvent()">Start Downtime Event</button> 
         <button ng-click="Model.StopDowntime()">Stop Downtime Event</button>
```

Comment: Are you saving the Input WHILE the user is typing, or only AFTER he clicked the button?

if the first: Just fetch the data on page load and put it inside the model.

if second: Im afraid there is no way to achieve this - maybe if you save the content in a cookie.

Comment: I'm saving the data after the user clicked the button.How can I achieve this while the user is typing?

Comment: I correct: See Ivica´s answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will go with localStorage - [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Basically, you are saving js objects in string in the browser, so you can get that data whenever you want, even after 10000 refresh or 5 months. This is more elegant way to store these type of data instead of cookies

> The data is stored in name/value pairs, and a web page can only access
>   data stored by itself.
>
> Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and
>   information is never transferred to the server.

Comment: Ah, of course, localStorage. Haha didnt even think of this.
This is the far better approach. I deleted my answer.

Comment: :) Modern time - modern technologies